# Bootstrap Login for Xpages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages

As all of our Xpages code is now going Bootstrap I want to bootstrap my log-in form.

I found this [code](http://xpagesbeast.com/uxdesign/customizing-the-html-log-in-form-with-bootstrap/). It is a little old, and I am having some difficulty getting it to work.

Is there a native Xpage log-in form? Could you have a custom log in form - but then set the property on the form to open an Xpage and log in from there?

Comment: Check OpenNTF...also your link has a typo in it

Comment: I believe the only way to force an XPages login form is similar to [this XSnippet](https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=redirect-to-xpages-login-page). I personally settled for [editing our `$$LoginUserForm` in our `domcfg.nsf` w/ some inline html](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/conf_customizingthehtmlloginform_t.dita) to make it Boostrap'd.

Answer (score 0):

I have one in my BS3 template (and in various other apps I created). Maybe you can just copy the source from here: https://github.com/zeromancer1972/Bootstrap-3-Template/blob/master/ODP/XPages/login.xsp